# A book about aliens amongst us and concept art

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

When I was in primary school (like mid 2000’s), in the school library there was a book about aliens living amongst us with concept art of them in a bar or a house looking quite futuristic with different looking beings and outfits. It was more of a picture and description book rather than just a novel.